# Condition on a directory having a git remote

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script to automatically update several directories of git repos, and I want to ignore repos that do not have a remote origin to pull from. So far I have

```
if git remote 2>&1 >/dev/null; then
```

which successfully determines whether a directory is a git repo. But for any new git repo,

```
git remote
```

returns "origin" and an error status of 0. How do I distinguish between such repos and a repo where the command `git pull` will do something?

I could use

```
git remote show origin
```

but this will connect to the origin server if it exists, and I'd prefer a command that's fast and local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check `.git/config` for the existence of `[remote "origin"]` ?

```
#/bin/bash
if grep -Fxq '[remote "origin"]' .git/config
then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If a repository has an *origin*, then the folder `.git/refs/remotes/origin` has to exist.

```
test -d .git/refs/remotes/origin
```

will return 0.

Comment: Not necessarily reliable, as `git` will at some point decide to start using packed refs instead of the directory hierarchy.